# автоматический пересчет корзины вукоммерс по изменению количества товаров

Tags: woocommerce, корзина

подскажите, как настроить пересчет итоговой суммы по кликам на + или - .

на сайте работает плагин Quantity Plus Minus Button for WooCommerce by CodeAstrology
он меняет количество товаров по кликам по + или  -  но обновлять итог корзины  опять нужно вручную. как можно совместить?
Попробовала такой вариант:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

  // отслеживаем изменение количества товара
 $( 'body' ).on( 'change', '.qty', function() { 

  // удаляем атрибут disabled(по умолчанию) , чтобы кнопка "Обновить корзину" стала активной
        $('[name="update_cart"]').removeAttr('disabled');

 // имитируем клик по кнопке "Обновить корзину" для пересчета
        $( '[name="update_cart"]' ).trigger( 'click' );
    } );

 } );
```

все это работает одноразово. страница перегружается, но выбивает другие events,  например нет вызова Попапа.   и уже далее .trigger  не работает.  [image: вот Html страницы]

Answer (score 0):

Корзины или миникорзины?
корзины Ajax Cart AutoUpdate for WooCommerce
мимникорзины - вариантов масса, нужно искать подходщий, папример https://opttour.ru/scripts-and-jquery/mini-korzina-v-header/

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо! решила обойтись без плагина, а вот по вашей ссылке на сайт нашла разные Доработки для Woocommerce - https://opttour.ru/plugins/dorabotka-funktsionala-woocommerce/.   там есть вариант, похожий на мой в вопросе.